# Что делает throw?

Tags: c++, исключения

При выполнение данного кода произошло создание трех объектов.
Если происходит создание одного или двух - я могу понять логику.
А при трех представить последовательность не получается.

1 объект: `throw` просто переводит выполнение на строку за подходящую `catch`-метку.

2 объекта: для объекта-операнда оператора `throw` создается копия, затем  вызывается деструктор для `obj`, выполнение переходит на подходящую метку `catch`, выполняется тело метки, для копии вызывается деструктор.

```
class A
{
public:
    A(){ cout << "Constructor A" << endl;};
    A(const A &obj){ cout << "Copy A" << endl;};
    A& operator=(const A & obj){cout << "Assigment A" << endl; return *this;};
    ~A(){cout << "Destructor A" << endl;};
};


int main(void)
{
    try
    {
        A obj;
        throw obj;
    }
    catch(A object)
    {
        cout << "Hello!!!" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы:

```
Constructor A
Copy A
Destructor A
Copy A
Hello!!!
Destructor A
Destructor A
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все верно - создание копии для "бросания", уничтожение объекта в `try`-блоке, далее, поскольку вы передаете исключение в `catch` **по значению**, а не по ссылке - еже одно копирование. И под конец удаление обоих оставшихся объектов.

Напишите

```
catch(A& object)
```

и объектов будет только два.